# How to get the TO email in the smtp log

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange, smtp

Is there a way to get the TO email address in the smtp log on Windows Server 2003 Exchange?

We have about 14,000 email addresses in our databases, and send out about 100 emails a day to customers. A lot of customers go for months or years between orders so we get about a dozen returned mail messages a day, the errors are the usual, no user by that name, no dns record found, mailbox full etc.

I would like to be able to automatically (using php) find the bad emails by parsing the log.

I already know how to try to do this with php so that's not the question.

I have all the fields checked that the log can show, but when I send an email, the log doesn't show the TO address, just the status code, error message, the other servers name,  etc.

Is there a way to show this, OR is there another file that I can be looking at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [message tracking logs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246965) are probably your best bet because they contain fairly complete information about the message and delivery attempts and are easily parsed text files.

Comment: Sweet, didn't know about that feature, probably exactly what I need, thanks!